# SQL retrieving data matter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$sql = "SELECT distinct `customer_id` FROM( SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `confirmed` = 1 ORDER BY `reserve_date` DESC ) as inv";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Run perfectly in the model php of codeigniter file for the cms

Have a column named "name" in table named "customer"
Would like to order the `data(customer_id)` obtained in `$query` by field "name" of table named "customer" and store it in `$result`
Then, do what ever I like with `$result`

How to do it - Please help me - am new to codeigniter and php. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your question is vague, please write it properly.

Comment: -what don't  u understand-

Comment: -pls tell me- others understand-

Comment: sorry about that but I am not able to got your question.

Comment: its ok - thank you - shanusingh

Comment: why downvote suddenly - after so long

Comment: I did not downvote this and hence I am wandering who downvote this.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to customer table and sort by the name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    customer_id
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        booking
    WHERE
        confirmed = 1
    ORDER BY reserve_date DESC) AS inv
        INNER JOIN
    customer AS cu ON cu.id = inv.customer_id
ORDER BY cu.name
```

If you never will use LIMIT in subquerying from "booking" you can optimize it by replacing

```
ORDER BY reserve_date DESC
```

with

```
ORDER BY null
```

And then you can even rewrite your query to become

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    inv.customer_id
FROM
    booking AS inv
        INNER JOIN
    customer AS cu ON cu.id = inv.customer_id
WHERE
    inv.confirmed = 1
ORDER BY cu.name;
```

Don't forget to build necessary indexes on `id, customer_id, confirmed and name` columns.

Comment: how to index alexander - thanks

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm

Accept the answer I answered your question :)

Comment: @websuccess this looks like the right answer

Answer (score 0):

$sql = SELECT DISTINCT booking.customer_id
FROM booking
INNER JOIN customer ON booking.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE `confirmed` = 1 
ORDER BY customer.name